# Create a directory, but fail if it already exists

Tags: c#, .net, directory

The standard .NET Directory.CreateDirectory(string path) method creates a directory (including parent directories, if needed), if they don't already exists, and returns a DirectoryInfo object for the created directory.

And if the directory does already exist, it returns a DirectoryInfo object for the directory that was already there.

I need a method that will create a directory, if it doesn't already exist, but will fail - returning an error or throwing an exception - if the directory already exists.

And no, Directory.Exists(string path) will not serve. I need something that is atomic.  I'm interfacing with C++ apps that were designed to the the presence or absence of certain directories as locks, and doing DirectoryExists() followed by Directory.CreateDirectory() leaves a window that can be stepped on.

At the filesystem level, creating a directory is an atomic operation. If two processes both attempt it, only one will succeed. And the API available to C++ programs reflects this. The standard API in .NET hides this. Is there some lower-level API that is available that does not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider using native [CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via [Interop](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CreateDirectory.html):

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);
}
```

If it fails because the directory exists, the function returns `false` and [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should return `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` [(decimal 183 or 0xB7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS** The specified directory already exists.

Please note **@stijn**'s remark however:

> Small caveat: `CreateDirectory` also returns if `lpPathName` points to an existing file so one might wrongly assume it is a directory.

Comment: That works.  One thing - if you aren't specifying security attributes, instead of passing null, pass IntPtr.Zero.

Comment: Small caveat: CreateDirectory also returns if lpPathName points to an existing *file* so one might wrongly assume it is a directory.

Comment: @stijn Good point, thanks! I incorporated it into the answer.